# Why does this program always respond with not responding message on the user interface? python code using pycrypto

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, encryption, pycrypto

So I am trying to run this program which used to work absolutely fine like 2 weeks ago and now it just shows that the user interface is not responding once I select the image and use the encrypt functionality. Last time I let it run for an hour or two and the program created an encrypted image but there's no way I am waiting this long for it to produce an output. Like I said, it ran under 10 seconds two weeks ago but not anymore and I have not been able to figure out what the actual problem is since I am a newbie to python programming.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
import tkMessageBox
import os
import PIL
import math
from PIL import Image
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
import binascii
import base64

global password  # make pass global var


# encryption method
# -----------------
def encrypt(imagename, password):
    # initialize variables
    plaintext = list()
    plaintextstr = ""

    # load the image
    im = Image.open(imagename)  # open target image
    pix = im.load()

    # print im.size   # print size of image (width,height)
    width = im.size[0]
    height = im.size[1]

    # break up the image into a list, each with pixel values and then append to a string
    for y in range(0, height):
        # print("Row: %d") %y  # print row number
        for x in range(0, width):
            # print pix[x,y]  # print each pixel RGB tuple
            plaintext.append(pix[x, y])

    # add 100 to each tuple value to make sure each are 3 digits long.  being able to do this is really just a PoC
    # that you'll be able to use a raw application of RSA to encrypt, rather than PyCrypto if you wanted.
    for i in range(0, len(plaintext)):
        for j in range(0, 3):
            plaintextstr = plaintextstr + "%d" % (int(plaintext[i][j]) + 100)

    # length save for encrypted image reconstruction
    relength = len(plaintext)

    # append dimensions of image for reconstruction after decryption
    plaintextstr += "h" + str(height) + "h" + "w" + str(width) + "w"

    # make sure that plantextstr length is a multiple of 16 for AES.  if not, append "n".  not safe in theory
    # and i should probably replace this with an initialization vector IV = 16 * '\x00' at some point.  In practice
    # this IV buffer should be random.
    while (len(plaintextstr) % 16 != 0):
        plaintextstr = plaintextstr + "n"

    # encrypt plaintext
    obj = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(plaintextstr)

    # write ciphertext to file for analysis
    cipher_name = imagename + ".crypt"
    g = open(cipher_name, 'w')
    base64_ciphertext = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)
    g.write(base64_ciphertext)

    # -----------------
    # construct encrypted image (not currently using since Tkinter isn't very nice)
    # -----------------
    def construct_enc_image():
        # hexlify the ciphertext
        asciicipher = binascii.hexlify(ciphertext)

        # replace function
        def replace_all(text, dic):
            for i, j in dic.iteritems():
                text = text.replace(i, j)
            return text

        # use replace function to replace ascii cipher characters with numbers
        reps = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4', 'e': '5', 'f': '6', 'g': '7', 'h': '8', 'i': '9', 'j': '10',
                'k': '11', 'l': '12', 'm': '13', 'n': '14', 'o': '15', 'p': '16', 'q': '17', 'r': '18', 's': '19',
                't': '20', 'u': '21', 'v': '22', 'w': '23', 'x': '24', 'y': '25', 'z': '26'}
        asciiciphertxt = replace_all(asciicipher, reps)

        # construct encrypted image
        step = 3
        encimageone = [asciiciphertxt[i:i + step] for i in range(0, len(asciiciphertxt), step)]
        # if the last pixel RGB value is less than 3-digits, add a digit a 1
        if int(encimageone[len(encimageone) - 1]) < 100:
            encimageone[len(encimageone) - 1] += "1"
        # check to see if we can divide the string into partitions of 3 digits.  if not, fill in with some garbage RGB values
        if len(encimageone) % 3 != 0:
            while (len(encimageone) % 3 != 0):
                encimageone.append("101")

        encimagetwo = [(int(encimageone[int(i)]), int(encimageone[int(i + 1)]), int(encimageone[int(i + 2)])) for i in
                       range(0, len(encimageone), step)]

        # make sizes of images equal
        while (int(relength) != len(encimagetwo)):
            encimagetwo.pop()

        # encrypted image
        encim = Image.new("RGB", (int(width), int(height)))
        encim.putdata(encimagetwo)

        encim.show()
        # alert success and path to image
        enc_success(cipher_name)

    construct_enc_image()
# decryption method
# -----------------
def decrypt(ciphername, password):
    # reach ciphertext into memory
    cipher = open(ciphername, 'r')
    ciphertext = cipher.read()
    denc = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)

    # decrypt ciphertext with password
    obj2 = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
    decrypted = obj2.decrypt(denc)

    # parse the decrypted text back into integer string
    decrypted = decrypted.replace("n", "")

    # extract dimensions of images
    newwidth = decrypted.split("w")[1]
    newheight = decrypted.split("h")[1]

    # replace height and width with emptyspace in decrypted plaintext
    heightr = "h" + str(newheight) + "h"
    widthr = "w" + str(newwidth) + "w"
    decrypted = decrypted.replace(heightr, "")
    decrypted = decrypted.replace(widthr, "")

    # reconstruct the list of RGB tuples from the decrypted plaintext
    step = 3
    finaltextone = [decrypted[i:i + step] for i in range(0, len(decrypted), step)]
    finaltexttwo = [
        (int(finaltextone[int(i)]) - 100, int(finaltextone[int(i + 1)]) - 100, int(finaltextone[int(i + 2)]) - 100) for
        i in range(0, len(finaltextone), step)]

    # reconstruct image from list of pixel RGB tuples
    newim = Image.new("RGB", (int(newwidth), int(newheight)))
    newim.putdata(finaltexttwo)
    newim.show()


# ---------------------
# GUI stuff starts here
# ---------------------

# empty password aler
def pass_alert():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Password Alert", "Please enter a Valid password.")


def enc_success(imagename):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Success", "Encrypted Image: " + imagename)


# image encrypt button event
def image_open():
    # useless for now, may need later
    global file_path_e

    # check to see if password entry is null.  if yes, alert
    enc_pass = passg.get()
    if enc_pass == "":
        pass_alert()
    else:
        password = hashlib.sha256(enc_pass).digest()
        filename = askopenfilename()
        file_path_e = os.path.dirname(filename)
        # encrypt the image
        encrypt(filename, password)


# image decrypt button event
def cipher_open():
    # useless for now, may need later
    global file_path_d

    # check to see if password entry is null.  if yes, alert
    dec_pass = passg.get()
    if dec_pass == "":
        pass_alert()
    else:
        password = hashlib.sha256(dec_pass).digest()
        filename = askopenfilename()
        file_path_d = os.path.dirname(filename)
        # decrypt the ciphertext
        decrypt(filename, password)


# main gui app starts here
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # make passg global to use in functions
        global passg
        # setup frontend titles etc blah blah
        title = "   Image Encryptor"
        author = ""
        msgtitle = Message(master, text=title, fg="red")
        msgtitle.config(font=("Times", "24", "bold italic"), width=200)
        msgauthor = Message(master, text=author)
        msgauthor.config(font=("helvetica", "15", "bold"), width=200)

        # draw canvas
        canvas_width = 350
        canvas_height = 100
        w = Canvas(master,
                   width=canvas_width,
                   height=canvas_height)

        # pack the GUI, this is basic, we shold use a grid system
        msgtitle.pack()
        msgauthor.pack()
        w.pack()

        # password field here above buttons
        passlabel = Label(master, text="Enter Encryption/Decryption Password:", font=30)
        passlabel.pack()
        passg = Entry(master, show="*", width=50)
        passg.pack()

        # add both encrypt/decrypt buttons here which trigger file browsers
        self.encrypt = Button(master,
                              text="Encrypt", fg="red", font=20,
                              command=image_open, width=20, height=2)
        self.encrypt.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.decrypt = Button(master,
                              text="Decrypt", fg="blue", font=20,
                              command=cipher_open, width=20, height=2)
        self.decrypt.pack(side=RIGHT)


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Image Encryptor")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

It uses old python packages. Kindly tell me what the problem is, thank you. There are comments in the code for better understanding.

Comment: if it was running smoothly few days ago but not anymore then this is in relation with your system not the code, you may ran an update or libraries update, accidentally deleted a dependency ect...you need to know the events happened during the smoothly ran, so you could know which event triggered the code to not run as smoothly as it was, check your system events log

Comment: do you mind running it in yours and see what the problem is? i have done it in the other system too but the same problem persists, keeps telling the program is not responding for like an hour or two and finally creates the output image.

Comment: actually iam outside using smartphone,

Comment: ah alrighty, feel free to help me in next 5 hours or something, i can wait.

Comment: Is this much code necessary? Can you just show the part which triggers the behavior?

Comment: Maybe your `root.mainloop()` blocked by some code for GUI refresh, like im.show(), or long time running.

Comment: @CoolCloud I do not know what triggers a not responding thing on a gui

Comment: It depends, a `while` loop or `time.sleep()` or any other type of window, that has its own loop, can make the GUI freeze while that process is running